# How do i use nested model with none value in pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
class Emails(BaseModel):
    Type: int
    Value: str = None
    IsPrimary: bool

class User(BaseModel):
   Emails: List[Emails] = None

INPUT :- User('Emails': [{'Type': 0, 'Value': 'qwert@gmail.com', 'IsPrimary': true}, 
                        {'Type': 1, 'Value': 'qpoefk@outlook.com', 'IsPrimary': true}])
```

Here pydantic is a python module and the Emails class inherit the BaseModel of pydantic
Type is an integer and Value is a string and IsPrimary is boolean.
Getting error when I pass the json string to the class

```
File "pydantic\main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for users_record
Emails -> 0
  value is not None (type=type_error.not_none)
Emails -> 1
  value is not None (type=type_error.not_none)
Phones -> 0
  value is not None (type=type_error.not_none)
Phones -> 1
  value is not None (type=type_error.not_none)
```

Comment: Does `Optional[str]` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same model name and field name `Emails`, this leads to an error. Give a different name for example:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    Emails: List[Email] = None
```

Comment: can you look into this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972093/how-to-get-values-from-nested-pydantic-classes