# How to get values from nested pydantic classes?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```py
class mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: int
    email: str
    
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    mails: List[mail]

data = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'mails':[
        {'mailid':1,'email':'aeajhs@gmail.com'}, 
        {'mailid':2,'email':'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}
    ]
}
    
userobj = User(**data)
```

How to get the value of `email` in `mail` class or `mailid` from `mail` class?

When I try to use `print(mail.email)` it throws error as

```
AttributeError: type object 'mail' has no attribute 'email'
```

When I use this got error too

```py
print(userobj.mails.email)
```

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'email'
```

When I use this I get data as follows

```py
print(userobj.mails)
[mail(mailid=1, email='aeajhs@gmail.com'), mail(mailid=2, email='aeajhsds@gmail.com')]
```

My desire output must be when I want to print email I must get `'aeajhs@gmail.com','aeajhsds@gmail.com'`

Comment: can i get mails as dictonary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access the class rather than the instance.

Here's one way of doing it:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: int
    email: str

one_mail = {"mailid": 1, "email": "aeajhs@gmail.com"}

mail = Mail(**one_mail)

print(mail)
# mailid=1 email='aeajhs@gmail.com'
```

With that in place, let's adapt the `User` model:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    mails: List[Mail]

data = {
    "id": 123, 
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "mails":[
        {"mailid": 1, "email": "aeajhs@gmail.com"}, 
        {"mailid": 2, "email": "aeajhsds@gmail.com"}
    ]
}

userobj = User(**data)

print(userobj.mails)
# [Mail(mailid=1, email='aeajhs@gmail.com'), Mail(mailid=2, email='aeajhsds@gmail.com')]
```

If you only need one of the email addresses, you need to specify which one, e.g.:

```py
print(userobj.mails[0].email)
# aeajhs@gmail.com
```

In order to get a list of all email addresses, you need to iterate over the `mails`, e.g.:

```py
print([mail.email for mail in userobj.mails])
# ['aeajhs@gmail.com', 'aeajhsds@gmail.com']
```

An as a side note: Pydantic supports [email string validation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#pydantic-types).

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'email'
```

means you are accessing an attribute of the `mails` list, not `mail` object.

You should pick the object from the list first using an index:

```
print(userobj.mails[0].email)
```

And, if you want every email of every `mails` instance, do

```
print([mail.email for mail in userobj.mails])
```